# How does the host command find results?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, dns, nameserver

I don't know if this is the right SE site for it, sorry if it isn't.

My problem: When I do a `host` (debian command) request for the TXT records of a domain, lets take superuser.com for example, can superuser.com, in any way, see the origin IP of my server?

My current understanding of the process:
When I enter the command, it sends a request to my configured nameserver in resolv.conf (for example 1.1.1.1), then 1.1.1.1 will send a request, with my server IP in the request header, to the configured nameserver of superuser.com and get the TXT records back to me.

Is this correct? Can I somehow make this anonymous since I am running a verification system for my website and I don't want my server attacked.

Comment: the upstream DNS server should not include your IP address in the queries it sends on to other server, but if the resolving server is in iterative mode, it will simply respond to you with the next server you should query in order to get your answer (forcing you to then directly query the authoritative server, using your own IP address). if your upstream server is in recursive mode however, it should get you the answer without exposing your ip to the authoritative server. https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-recursive-dns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two methods to be sure of totally hiding your IP address
from being visible when issuing a DNS request:

- Use a VPN (one that doesn't suffer from DNS leak)
- Use the TOR network.

Comment: @Op, note that dns leakage is a big topic with both VPNs and TOR, and should be handled carefully. make sure you are using a  VPN that uses a Virtual network adapter that takes over the default route and that the endpoints DNS server assignment doesn't point to your router or a LAN DNS server for that interface. you need your DNS traffic to traverse the tunnel, and not bypass it.